# As soon as I restrict my Google API key it no longer works

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I have a Google API key that I'm using and has been working fine for Google maps. I am now trying to use the Google Maps Distance Matrix API with my Android app and I can only get it to work if I don't restrict my key to my Android app. As soon as I restrict the key to my package and SHA1 fingerprint it no longer works. I double checked the package name from the AndroidManifest and I made sure I'm using the right keystore & alias combination but it doesn't seem to matter. Is there anything else I can check for?

Comment: I don't see how that particular API works on mobile similar to the main Google Maps for Android product. Have you tried calling the API endpoint via HTTP/JSON with a designated key?

Comment: no longer works means what ? what is the response you get

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to use the same release key as I use for my Google Maps key. I have tried using a new key but it's the same result as I described. Google maps API works fine, this new feature with Distance Matrix API does not work. Result is empty dataset in mobile. Can't test with Postman because it's restricted to Android and I get the relevant message in the response there. I can't figure out why the response is empty on Android. The code works if the same key is unrestricted.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that Android app restriction is valid only for Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps Places for Android. Web services (e.g. Distance Matrix API) will not work with this restriction.

The restrictions that will work with an API keys for web services are IP restrictions.

It is supposed that web services requests are executed on your backend servers. If you need to restrict an API key, the workaround is to create an intermediate server. Your Android application should send requests to the intermediate server, intermediate server should send requests to Google and pass responses back to your app. In this case you can restrict an API key by IP address of your intermediate server.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still accurate? I use a key for the cloud translation API. I restricted the key to my android app and the requests no longer work.